# Making Executable C++ file user friendly so someone can run it like an app or software

Tags: c++, executable

I wrote a small c++ program to help a family member to automate some of their functions. How can I send it to them and give them ability to run it as if it was an app or at least without them having to run it in terminal (using ./a.out) and/or write command lines?

Basically where they would just click on a file and it will run with the prompts right away.

Comment: Depends on the OS you want to run your application

Comment: Running on Mac.

Comment: Please see the [tour], the [ask] page and the [help/on-topic] to see why this is getting downvoted and will likely be voted closed. It's way too broad of a question and seems to be mostly opinion-based.

Comment: How is the question opinion based? I am asking a question on how to do something. @RandomDavis

Comment: On the Mac, click-to-run apps are usually created with Cocoa, and, these days, often written in Swift.  Download and install Xcode from the App Store (it's free).  There are templates in there to get you started.

Comment: @user18051530 the question isn't opinion based, but lacks details and clarity, and needs to be more focused.

Comment: @user18051530 arguing with people that are trying to help you isn't going to do you any favors. Also you're asking how to do a very broad thing, and there's many ways to go about it; maybe it's not up to someone's opinion, but more of their preference. Like, a GUI, or just have an executable file that just runs the program right away, possibly asking the user for input. It all depends on your requirements, which you didn't specify. I didn't cast a vote saying that this was an opinion-based post. There's no single way to answer your vague question though.

Comment: Thank you so much @PaulSanders for giving a good place to start and being patient with me.

Comment: If you don't want the user to have to interact with a console/terminal, then don't write a console/terminal app to begin with. Sounds like you want a GUI app (or a GUI-less background app) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to know the runtime environment of your family member's pc. So mainly operating system and cpu architecture. Than porting your application can be achieved by cross-compiling.

For example take a look into the mingw-w64 toolchain to cross-compile to windows (as I assume that you are on linux).

However, I would advise to move to any interpreted languages such as Python or to Java which runs in their own environment that doesn't need cross-compiling to other machines! Depending on your application this can be a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know your exact need, maybe all you want is to compile your code to an executable:

```sh
c++ main.cpp -o SomeApp
```

Now, it creates an executable, and you can simply double click it to run.

---

If you actually want an app with some GUI running on Mac, you can still create one quite easily with Xcode. When you open Xcode, you can select the template `macOS->App`, and select `SwiftUI` for interface, and it should automatically create couple files, and have the file named `ContentView` opened for you.

On the left, you will see a file navigator, and you can drag your `a.out` file in there to have it included in the project. On the right is the template code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
        .padding()
    }
}
```

All you need is to change the line with `Text` to:

```swift
Button("Run")
{
    try! Process.run(URL(fileURLWithPath: "/bin/zsh"), arguments: [
        "-c", Bundle.main.path(forResource: "a", ofType: "out")!
    ])
}
```

This will create a button that runs `a.out` through `zsh` upon clicked:
[image]

---

However, this is unlikely to satisfy all your needs. Depends on your exact need, you might need to learn a lot more about SwiftUI and application design in general to create an effective app.